# How do I multiply elements using conditional statement?

Tags: r, function, matrix

I am very new to R and programming in general, and I need some help. I want to make a function that multiplies all even numbers in a given matrix by 3, for instance in this matrix:

```
X = matrix(1:9,3,3)
```

I have tried the replace function like this:

```
Multiply = function(M) {
 x=M*3
 replace(M, M%%2==0, x)
}
```

wich gives me a result I don't understand. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: use `ifelse` to do this or `Multiply <- function(M){
   i1 <- M%%2 == 0;
   M[i1] <- M[i1]*3;
   M
}`

Comment: Thank you! That was easy to understand.

Comment: Or `X*(1 + 2*(X %% 2 == 0))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create the function as

```
Multiply <- function(M){ i1 <- M%%2 == 0
          M[i1] <- M[i1]*3
          M }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for your example:

```
mymult <-function(M, num.row, num.col){
    vec = c(M)
    vec[vec %% 2 == 0]=vec[vec%%2 == 0]*3
    return(matrix(vec, num.row, num.col))
}
```

vectorizes first and checks which are even and multiplies those with three and reconstructs the matrix again.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I have figured out a solution!